# Why skinPercent() so slow?

Tags: maya, skin

I want to copy skin weights from one human model to another. The two models have the same topology, so I tried to directly copy the weight index by index using following code.

```py
for idx, p in enumerate(points):
  # skinValues save first model's skinning
  if idx in skinValues.keys():
    ns = skinValues[str_idx]
    mc.skinPercent(skinClusterIm, p, tv = ns,zri = True)
```

But it works so slowly (for models with 50000 vertices and 300 joints takes 15 minutes). Is there any way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will be painfully slow sadly, because Maya is generating an undo step for every single iteration sadly. That's 50000 * 300 undo steps, which is quite a lot of memory allocation!

You have two options to speed this up.

**Option 1:** disable the undo queue!

```
// grab current undo state
current_state = mc.undoInfo(q = True, state=True)

// turn off the undo queue
mc.undoInfo(state=False)


// call skinPercent in your double nested for loop now


// restore the state of the undo queue
mc.undoInfo(state = current_state)
```

**Option 2:** Modify the skin cluster data directly.

The data on the skin cluster is addressed like so:

```cpp
skinCluster1.wl[VERTEX_INDEX].w[JOINT_INDEX];
```

You can skip the need to skinPercent command entirely, by simply using setAttr to set the weights directly. I'm a bit old school, so generally use MEL, but in MEL you can set all weights for a single vertex in a single command, e.g.

```
// this assume the skin cluster has 4 weights per vertex! 
// So we set vertex 0: wl[0], 
// 
// using joint indices 0, 1, 2, and 3; i.e. ".w[0:3]", 
// 
// We can then just list the weights we want to set afterwards.
// 
setAttr "skinCluster1.wl[0].w[0:3]"   0.666 0.334 0 0;
```

Even with the undo stack enabled, this helps trim down the number of undo steps (However, even with this approach, I'd still disable the undo stack!!). By and large, I'd **avoid** using MFnSkinCluster in the Maya API, because it's stupidly slow. Sadly, the skinPercent command is clearly implemented using MFnSkinCluster :(

\edit

a little Mel script to extract the joint names from the skin cluster.

```cpp
proc print_joints(string $cluster) {
    // how big is the matrix array input on the cluster?
    // this will map directly to the number of joints in 
    // the cluster
    $num_joints = `getAttr -size ($cluster + ".matrix")`;
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_joints; ++$i) {

        // look for any source connections to the given array input
        $joint = `listConnections -d 0 -s 1 ($cluster + ".matrix[" + $i + "]")`;

        // print in a readable format
        print($cluster + ".matrix[" + $i + "] --> connected to --> " + $joint[0] + "\n");
    }
}

print_joints("skinCluster1");
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Another related question is can I get mapping relationship between JOINT_INDEX and JOINT_NAME using something like getAttr()? jointNames = mc.skinPercent(skinCluster, point, query=True, transform=None) is also very slow.

Comment: See the script above. Just look for the nodes connected to the `skinCluster.matrix` input.

Comment: Thank you~these functions are exactly what I want, and now I can complete the entire process in only half a minute^^. In addition, is there any way to set all weights related to one point to zero? Like setAttr "skinCluster1.wl[0].w[:]"   0.0 0.0 0.0 .......